# Computing e^x was fine . But not sin of x

Tags: c, loops, math

I am quite new to coding. And I know this code also doesn't look very well designed. If I am not supposed to ask questions like this, please let me know. I will take it down and figure things out myself (hopefully).

My first program that calculated **e<sup>x</sup>** using Taylor series worked well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double calculateTaylorSeries(double x, int n) {
    double result = 1.0; // The first term in the series

    double term = 1.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        term *= x / i; 
        result += term; 
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    double x;

    printf("Enter the value of x: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x);

    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of terms (n): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    double taylorApproximation = calculateTaylorSeries(x, n);

    printf("e^%.2lf (approximated using %d terms): %lf\n", x, n, taylorApproximation);

    return 0;
}
```

But doing the same thing with the **sin** function seemed difficult. Since there is an alternating term aspect. And the power and the denominator has to be odd.

My logic seems fine to me. But it's giving me incorrect results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double calculateTaylorSeries(double x, int n)
{
    double result = x;
    double term = 1.0;
    int sign = -1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
        {
            term *= x / i * sign; //term = term * x/i * sign;

            result += term; // result = result + term;
        }
    }

    return result; 
}

int main(void)
{
    double x; 
    printf(" Enter the angle : ");

    scanf("%lf", &x);
    
    int n;
    
    printf("Enter the number of terms(n):");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    double sinX = calculateTaylorSeries(x, n);

    printf("sin(%lf) = %lf", x, sinX);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter the angle : 6.28
Enter the number of terms(n):2
sin(6.280000) = 13.146133
```

```
Enter the angle : 234
Enter the number of terms(n):15 
sin(234.000000) = -49592774856964366336.000000
```

And I am also confused why, when I am running this in VS code, It shows me this error:

`The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some errors in your term computation:

- you do not alternate the sign
- you skip the even factors in the term computation. You should only skip them in the summation.
- the initial value of `result` should be 0.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double calculateTaylorSeries(double x, int n) {
    double result = 0;
    double term = -1.0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2 * n; i++) {
        term *= x / i;
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            term = -term;
            result += term; // result = result + term;
        }
    }
    return result; 
}

int main(void) {
    double x; 
    printf("Enter the angle in radians: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &x) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number of terms(n):");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        return 1;

    double sinX = calculateTaylorSeries(x, n);
    printf("sin(%lf) = %lf", x, sinX);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I liked the way this answer preserves the OP's original way of working with a term, which wasn't beginner-like at all!

Comment: Yeah, And its also really cool to learn something like this, instead of learning it from a youtube vedio.

Answer (score 2):

The issues of the posted code are already mentioned in [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76842919/4944425).

Note that there's a way to "skip" the even indices, as long long as their factors are taken into account:

```
// six(x) = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - x^7/7!* + ...
//        = x + x*(-x^2)/(2*3) + x*(-x^2)*(-x^2)/(2*3 * 4*5) + ...
double sin_Taylor(double x, int n)
{
  double result = x;

  double x2 = - x * x;
  double term = x;

  for ( int i = 1; i < n; ++i )
  {
      term *= x2 / (((i * 2)) * (i * 2 + 1));
      //            2, 4, ...    3, 5, 7, ...
      result += term; 
  }
  return result; 
}
```

Live, here: https://godbolt.org/z/1G8c43GEv

Answer (score 1):

You do not change `sign` and in the loop you calculate only you skip even iterations.

Example of working code:

```
double fact(unsigned n)
{
    double result = 1;
    do
    {
        result *= n;
    }
    while(--n);
    return result;
}

double msin(double x, unsigned n)
{
    double result = x;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        result += (i % 2 ? 1 : -1) * pow(x, 3 + 2 * i) / fact(3 + 2 * i);
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    for(unsigned n = 2; n < 10; n++)
        printf("%.30f\n%.30f\n\n", msin(1.4, n), sin(1.4));
}
```

`n` - number of iterations.

https://godbolt.org/z/s3b3bEshW

Comment: I did not know you can do that. Thank you so much! But what was it I did wrong?

Comment: unfortunately not. But probably because I cant follow the synax.